# SQL Server Date Comparison issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I am trying to flag a field in a different table whenever two dates do not have the right relationship. However, All dates in the dataset should not flag anything(should be 0 instead of 1), but they all flag. Could it be an issue with the date format changing during the query? Really stuck here

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqaJa.png)

```
UPDATE Theatre_DQ_03_Integrity_CASES
SET AnaesToTheatreFlag = 1, TimeErrorFlag = 1
FROM Theatre_Cases_Landing a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  Case_ID
    FROM Theatre_Cases_Landing 
    WHERE (CaseCancelled IS NULL or CaseCancelled = 'N') AND (CONVERT(datetime,Anaesthetic_Start_DateTime) > CONVERT(datetime,In_Theatre_DateTime)) 
    AND Anaesthetic_Start_DateTime IS NOT NULL AND In_Theatre_DateTime IS NOT NULL
) b
ON a.Case_ID = b.Case_ID

declare @var1 as  datetime2 = '2019-09-04 11:12:00.000'
declare @var2 as  datetime2 = '2019-09-04 11:13:00.000' 
if @var1 < @var2 PRINT('TRUE')
```

Comment: I don't see a correlation between the target table (`Theatre_DQ_03_Integrity_CASES`) and the FROM/JOIN criteria so every row in the table will be updated.

Comment: @DanGuzman how do you go about solving this? the same inner join method seems to be working for other purposes? Both tables are related on Case Id thank you

Comment: Can you show one row in `Theatre_Cases_Landing` that you think is a problem?  Maybe your datetime comparison isn't correct for your requirement.  I assume you don't think `Anaesthetic_Start_DateTime` should ever be prior to `In_Theatre_DateTime` (for non-cancelled cases) and wish to `update` those cases.  If you can show any case (with datetimes) that isn't handled properly, that would help.

Comment: *Could it be an issue with the date format changing during the query?* - you store your datetimes in varchars?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correlate rows to be updated with the rows from the other table. Otherwise, every row in the target will be updated.

I don't see a need to self-join `Theatre_Cases_Landing`. Below is an untested version with the correlation.

```
UPDATE target
SET AnaesToTheatreFlag = 1, TimeErrorFlag = 1
FROM Theatre_DQ_03_Integrity_CASES AS target
JOIN Theatre_Cases_Landing AS a ON a.Case_ID = target.Case_ID
WHERE
    (a.CaseCancelled IS NULL or a.CaseCancelled = 'N')
    AND CONVERT(datetime,a.Anaesthetic_Start_DateTime) > CONVERT(datetime,a.In_Theatre_DateTime) 
    AND a.Anaesthetic_Start_DateTime IS NOT NULL
    AND a.In_Theatre_DateTime IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: that worked, thank you very much. It's only my second week using SQL so still learning! very helpful :)